# Display WooCommerce size product attribute on shop page

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I'm using this code to display size attributes below each product on the shop archive page, but it throws the error below. How do I change the code to fix this error? My thoughts the code has depreciated.

```
add_action('woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'add_attribute', 5);
function add_attribute() {
    $desired_att = 'Size';
    global $product;
    $product_variable = new WC_Product_Variable($product->id);
    $product_variations = $product_variable->get_available_variations();
    $numItems = count($product_variations);

    echo '<span class="price">';
    if ($numItems == 1) {
        foreach ($product_variations as $variation) {
            echo $variation[attributes]['attribute_pa_size'];
        }
    } else if ($numItems > 1) {
        $i = 0;
        foreach ($product_variations as $variation) {
            if (++$i === $numItems) {
                echo $variation[attributes]['attribute_pa_size'];
            } else {
                echo $variation[attributes]['attribute_pa_size'] . ", ";
            }
        }
    }
    echo '</span>';
}
```

Error Message

```
Notice: id was called
incorrectly
. Product properties should not be accessed directly. Backtrace: require('wp-blog-header.php'), require_once('wp-includes/template-loader.php'), include('/plugins/genesis-connect-woocommerce/templates/taxonomy.php'), genesis, do_action('genesis_loop'), WP_Hook->do_action, WP_Hook->apply_filters, genesiswooc_product_taxonomy_loop, genesiswooc_content_product, wc_get_template_part, load_template, require('/plugins/woocommerce/templates/content-product.php'), do_action('woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title'), WP_Hook->do_action, WP_Hook->apply_filters, add_attribute, WC_Abstract_Legacy_Product->__get, wc_doing_it_wrong Please see
Debugging in WordPress
for more information. (This message was added in version 3.0.) in
/home/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php
on line
4773
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is outdated since WooCommerce 3. 
First, you need to target variable products type only to avoid errors on other products types and also `$product` is already the product object.

Also you can also directly use the `WC_Product` method `get_attribute()` and your code will be much more simpler, compact and efficient:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'display_size_attribute', 5 );
function display_size_attribute() {
    global $product;

    if ( $product->is_type('variable') ) {
        $taxonomy = 'pa_size';
        echo '<span class="attribute-size">' . $product->get_attribute($taxonomy) . '</span>';
    }
}
```

*Code goes in functions.php file of the active child theme (or active theme).* Tested and works.

Comment: Thanks LoicTheAztec, works perfectly like you said.

Comment: The only thing that is missing: show item variation if in-stock.

Comment: @murrayac You can't ask multiple questions at once… The rule is for one question, one answer. So It's better to ask a new question for it, providing all necessary details. My answer here is answering your main question, and solving your issue.

Comment: Thanks, will do.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a product global object and it's methods in Woocommerce 4.3

```
add_action('woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'cstm_display_product_category', 5);

function cstm_display_product_category()
{
  global $product;
  $size = $product->get_attribute('pa_size');

 if(isset($size)){
    echo '<div class="items"><p>Size: ' . $size . '</p></div>';
 }
}
```